# extract data from two tables in a relationship, but have the data in one table only appear once

Tags: sql

I have two tables that I need to pull data from, 'Table A' and 'Table B'.  There is a a 1:M relationship between 'Table A' and 'Table B', with A.IDNumber as a Foreign Key in 'Table B'.

What I want to do is to extract the values from Table A once, and the corresponding values from 'Table B' without repeating the 'Table A' data.

What would my query look like to do this?  To help, let's say I want the following values from 'Table A': A.IDNumber, A.Amount, and from 'TableB' values B.IDNumber, B.Address, B.State, B.City, B.State, B.Zip.

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: What rdbms are you using?  sql server, mysql, oracle?  Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query below. Here's a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fadd9/3/0)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN IDNumber END IDNumber,
       CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN Amount END Amount,
       Address, City, State, Zip
FROM
(
  SELECT A.IDNumber, A.Amount,
         B.Address, B.City, B.STATE, B.Zip,
         RN = Row_number() over (partition BY A.IDNumber
                               ORDER BY B.IDNumber)
  FROM tableA A
  LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.IDNumber = B.IDNumber
) X
ORDER BY IDNumber, RN
```

It gives this output

```
IDNumber Amount ADDRESS CITY    STATE   ZIP
1        200.1  1 Public Road   Gotham  AX  19281
(null)  (null)  Secret Batcave  Gotham  AX  19281
(null)  (null)  Overseas Hideaway   Unspecified ??  n/a
2        312.45 John Woo Lane   Trespass    TX  12345
(null)  (null)  Address City    State   Sq-123
```

When given this sample table

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
  IDNumber int, Amount money)
CREATE TABLE TableB(
  IDNumber int,
  Address varchar(max),
  City varchar(max),
  State varchar(max),
  Zip varchar(max))
INSERT TableA SELECT
  1,200.10 union all select
  2,312.45
INSERT TableB SELECT
  1, '1 Public Road', 'Gotham', 'AX', '19281' union all select
  1, 'Secret Batcave', 'Gotham', 'AX', '19281' union all select
  1, 'Overseas Hideaway', 'Unspecified', '??', 'n/a' union all select
  2, 'John Woo Lane', 'Trespass', 'TX', '12345' union all select
  2, 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Sq-123'
```

Answer (score 0):

So you do not repeat values, use DISTINCT on your query

```
select **DISTINCT** A.IDNumber, A.Amount, and from 'TableB' values B.IDNumber, B.Address, B.State, B.City, B.State, B.Zip from TableA A, TableB B where A.IDNumber = B.IDNumber
```

Comment: The only problem with using distinct is that there may be other records associated with that idNumber that I do want in the results.  Thank  you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is that you want the fields from Table A only on the first row of results from B.

The way you do this depends on the database.  Here is an approach that will work with most databases:

```
with b as (
     select b.*,
            row_number() over (partition by b.a_idnumber order by b.idnumber) as seqnum
     from tableb
    )
select (case when b.seqnum = 1 then a.idnumber end) as IdNumber,
       (case when b.seqnum = 1 then a.amount end) as Amount,
       b.*
from tablea a join
     b
     on a.idnumber = b.a_idnumber
order by a.idnumber, b.seqnum
```

Comment: Thank you.  I implemented this and it has worked exactly as I wanted.